# Error sending USSD Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: asus, bios, dbus, huawei, ussd

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem.Modem3gpp.Ussd' on object at path /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/2
```

modem manager GUI work properly in ubuntu 13.10 after upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 Can't send USSD.I have a huawei E158 usb router and ASUS N53T laptop, Help me to solve this problem.

when i install ubuntu resevied this message! but i have latest bios[image]

Comment: When do you get this problem? What are you trying to do? Please describe the problem in greater detail.

Comment: @Jobin this occurs when sending USSD using modem manger in 14.04

Comment: @Thnzrmzwr It appears that your hardware may not be compatible with USSD. Are you sure that it is? The error states "UnknownMethod: No such interface"

Comment: @Thnzrmzwr Thank you for adding further information to your question. Have you updated the firmware? It looks like the latest for your e158 is 11.609.18.01.158 as of this date available here: http://huaweifirmwares.com/download/e158-firmware-update_11-609-18-01-158/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved new Modem Manager Version 0.017(Module Backend)
Change Module Backend
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the firmware. It looks like the latest for your e158 is 11.609.18.01.158 as of this date available here: http://huaweifirmwares.com/download/e158-firmware-update_11-609-18-01-158/. Failing that I've found that contacting the manufacturer is often helpful.

http://www.huawei.com/ilink/us/about-huawei/contact-us/index.htm

Comment: it's not compatible for ubuntu but it compatible for windows and mac

Comment: @Thnzrmzwr Edited answer